# how I call the source ~./.bash_profile script from another shell script?

Tags: bash, path

## I what to call source.sh script in another script main.sh script source.sh has following

```
   #!/bin/sh
    ~/.bash_profile



 #main.sh has following 
    tar -xzvf /home/admin/perf/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz >> /home/admin/perf/output.txt &&
    sleep 1
    echo "Export Path for Environmental Variable"
    sudo echo "export PATH=/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/:$PATH" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile
    sudo echo "export JAVA_HOME=:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile
    sleep 1
    echo "Persisting JDK PATH to .bash_profile"
    source /home/admin/perf/./source.sh

when I execute ./main.sh
    
#Result is ./source.sh script is not setting the export path in the same shell.
```

Answer (score 0):

`#!/usr/bin/bash` is for born again shell, meaning bash, on most systems this is what is the first line of a bash script, your line `#!/bin/sh` could be incorrect. but i might be wrong on this.

to call the bash_profile, you can enter `source ~/.bash_profile` but i would look at the first line which is the interpreter.

Comment: Tried with adding #!/usr/bin/bash in ./source.sh below is what it look like
#!/usr/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile

And main.sh script has below ( also tried with #!/usr/bin/bash got bad interpreter error)
#!/bin/sh
echo "Export Path for Environmental Variable"
sudo echo "export PATH=/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/:$PATH" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile
source /home/admin/perf/./path_persist.sh
======================================
No luck. issues it the same. Its not exporting the path in the same session.

Comment: For the exporting of `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` you should not need to use `echo` and the speech marks, otherwise you are using the command `echo` to output a string, and not importing the two environment variables which you would like to use.

Comment: `sudo echo "export PATH=/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/:$PATH" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile` works fine the PATH is appended with above details. Just that `source ~/.bash_profile` doesn't work in the same script. I spawn another session I see updated PATH in .bash_profile without running `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Entire Script after changing base don the inputs

Comment: Entire Script below based. Still need `source ~/.bash_profile` to be executed separately outside of script in order to see the PATH under export. Note- After running the below script if I spawn another session I do see the PATH exported. 
`#!/bin/bash
echo "Export Path for Environmental Variable"
sudo echo "export PATH=/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/:$PATH" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile
sudo echo "export JAVA_HOME=:/home/admin/perf/jdk1.8.0_201" >> /home/admin/.bash_profile
echo "Persisiting JDK PATH to .bash_profile"
source ~/.bash_profile`